# Insert stuff at every nth occurence of a character in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a file containing queries, each query ends with a ";", I want to add a "COMMIT;BEGIN;" every 100 queries. Queries can take more than 1 line.

For instance:

```
    INSERT INTO table
    VALUES(...);
    DELETE FROM table WHERE ...;
    UPDATE table
    SET ...;
```

So I want to replace every 100th ";" with "COMMIT;BEGIN;" (I know I have to add a BEGIN; at the beginning of the file and do something at the end but it's easy)

I need to do that in a shell script but I am not a Linux expert, is it better to use sed or awk (also the file size can be huge like 4GB)? I know the basics for those commands but I don't know if I can do what I want here...

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want that? I mean if your import fails you will have some rows interted but not all. That is bad in my opinion. So better add all rows in a huge transaction.

Comment: It's just for speed test purpose ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the `;` is at the end of the line, or if you don't really care about lines with multiple `;`'s, the easy solution (untested) is:

```
awk '/;/{ count+=1 } {print} count==100 { print "COMMIT; BEGIN"; count=0 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not to try to replace the semicolons. Instead, "parse" all the command and put `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` around the bunch of commands you want to commit. This is fairly easy with sed. If you have this file:

```
$ cat my.sql 
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO table VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO table VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO table VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO table VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO table VALUES (6);
INSERT INTO table VALUES (7);
INSERT INTO table VALUES (8);
INSERT INTO table VALUES (9);
INSERT INTO table VALUES (10);
```

just run this command:

```
$ sed -n 'H;${x;s/\([^;]*;\)\{,3\}/BEGIN;&\nCOMMIT;\n\n/g;p}' my.sql 
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO table VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO table VALUES (3);
COMMIT;

BEGIN;
INSERT INTO table VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO table VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO table VALUES (6);
COMMIT;

BEGIN;
INSERT INTO table VALUES (7);
INSERT INTO table VALUES (8);
INSERT INTO table VALUES (9);
COMMIT;

BEGIN;
INSERT INTO table VALUES (10);
COMMIT;
```

(Here I am using 3 as the size of the block for clarity. For "embracing" blocks of 100 commands, replace `\{,3\}` with  `\{,100\}`)

What does it do?

- First, we inhibit the printing of lines with `-n`. Now sed will only print lines when we order it to print them explicitly.
- Now, for each line, we append the line to the hold space with `H`.
- At the last line (address `$`) we execute a block of commands (beginning at `{` and ending at `}`). The first command, `x`, swaps the content of the hold space (which now contains all the file) and the pattern space.
- After this, we replace with `s///` n (0 < n <= 3) series of characters (none being `;`) followed by `;` with the string `BEGIN;`, the matched block of commands (represented by `&`) and the string `\nCOMMIT;\n\n` (with newlines for better readability.
- At last, we print the content of the pattern space with `p`.

Comment: Thanks for the sed trick, if I was able to pick 2 correct answers I would add yours ;)

Comment: @MaximeLaval no problem, you should accept the best solution for your problem. I am sufficiently happy to believe my answer is useful and, for me, sed-fu is a really funny game which pays itself :P

Answer (score 0):

If the semicolons are at the end of the line:

```
awk '{print} /;$/ && ! (count++%100) {print "COMMIT; BEGIN;"}' inputfile
```

If it's important that precisely 100 semicolons are counted and they may be anywhere in a line it can be done but it gets a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed);

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/^\([^;]*\(;[^\n][^;]*\)*;\s*$\)\{100\}/&\nCOMMIT;BEGIN;/mg' file
```